# Locate ArcGIS documentation data resources (shapefiles)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, documentation

Esri's official website provides documentation for ArcGIS and ArcGIS Pro's tools and they provide examples with certain shapefiles. And I want to practice those examples with certain shapefiles. But I can't find the shapefiles. How can I get those resources?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This seems like an awful way to try to learn Pro. While most of the data is likely available (if you try asking Tech Support), using an actual tutorial is far more likely to be productive.

Answer (score 1):

The code samples are for understanding the syntax of a specific command. They are not intended to be full tutorials with attached data. If you want to do a full tutorial (including attached data) take a look at some of the tutorials Esri has listed on their [ArcGIS Pro Resource page](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-pro/resources), especially the Analysis and Modeling tutorials.

Otherwise I would recommend reading the tool description, taking an educated guess on what types of data (e.g. point, line, polygon, raster) are required as input, find that kind of data in your own work or online, and try the tool out in your own "tutorial". For example, for the Clip tool shown in your question they show a roads dataset being clipped by a study area (polygon) and a set of building footprints being clipped by a campus boundary. You could download roads data and municipal boundaries from the US Census as a variation on the first code example.